# Django. When adding an image, create a folder corresponding to the object id

Tags: django

I created a model, it has a line for the image:

```
photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

In the example, if I add an image, a folder is created with the date of adding
I wish that when add an image, create a folder with the `"id"` of the object.

Please tell me the solutions!
Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Create a folder where? s3? local storage? What have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First create a method for the directory:

```
from datetime import date

def image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join([date.today().strftime('photos/%Y/%m/%d'), str(instance.id), filename])
```

Then pass the method to the `ImageField`'s `upload_to` parameter:

```
photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
```

Comment: **little edit**. If you copy the example, you get an error `sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found`. I added str(instance.id). Everything works very nicely. Thanks again, **ruddra** ! In my Russian community, all some evil, and do not answer the questions of newbies

Comment: If the photos belong to the same object, and you want to create a new object and save the photos in the same time, the name of the folder (instance.id) will be None. any solution for that?